# animating text view text change using animate layout changes (LayoutTransition.CHANGING)

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, textview

I've followed a tutorial to animate text change on text view in order to implement (Read more) in comments and such, so far it animates when extending the text but not when collapsing text.

How can i animate on collapse?

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbs16.gif)

fragment

```
private var extended = false
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val testTextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test_text)
        val container = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.text_view_container)

        val comment = /*Long comment*/

        //animate text change
        container.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(
            LayoutTransition.CHANGING
        )

        if ((comment.length ?: 0) <= 200) {
            testTextView.text = comment
        } else {
            testTextView.text =
                comment.substring(
                    0, if (comment.length < 200) comment.length else 200
                )
        }


        testTextView.setOnClickListener {
            extended = !extended
            if (extended) {
                testTextView.text = comment

            } else {
                testTextView.text = comment.substring(
                    0, (if (comment.length < 200) comment.length else 200)
                )
            }
        }

    }
```

XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_blank_root"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried setting other layout transition but it did not work.
I am expecting it to animate on collapse